# Image Window is always remains open and in hanged state

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I am new to openCv with python. I am able to open the image window, but on any key press,image window hangs and does not get closed

```
import cv2 
input = cv2.imread('/Users/chetandev/Desktop/testimage.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Hello World', input)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path is probably wrong in some way. You can put `testimage.jpg` in the same folder as the codes, and do `cv2.imread('testimage.jpg')`.

From here:
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#display-image

`Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but print img will give you None`

You can probably check if the image is properly loaded by using `if input is None`. You should probably also put `0` in the argument for `cv2.waitKey()`.

Comment: `cv2.waitKey()` takes 0 by default

Comment: not working even after putting the image in  same folder